What is the connection between $P(Y\in B|\sigma(X))$ and $P(Y\in B|X \in A)$?
Given a probability space $(\Omega,{\mathcal F},P)$. And two random varible $X,Y:(\Omega,{\mathcal F}) \rightarrow (S,{\mathcal S})$ measurable. If we want to caltulate the probablity of the event $$P(X\in A, Y \in B),A,B\in {\mathcal S}.$$ And we have knew $P(X\in A)$ and $P(Y\in B|\sigma(X))$, where $\sigma(X)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $X$ in $\Omega$. By the formula of conditional probablity, we have
\begin{equation}
P(X\in A, Y \in B)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B|X\in A)
\end{equation}
Since we have knew $P(X\in A)$, we can get what we desire only by calculate $P(Y\in B|X\in A)$.
$\textbf{My question is: whether can we know}$ $P(Y\in B|X\in A)$ $\textbf{just from}$ $P(Y\in B|\sigma(X))$ ?
If yes, how can we get the consequence, and if not, what other information is required?

It is not a well-posed question, it is unclear what do you mean by "can we know".
By definition, $P(Y \in B \mid \sigma(X))$ is the random variable, measurable relative to $\sigma(X),$ such that for every Borel set $A,$ $P(Y \in B, X \in A) = E(P(Y \in B \mid \sigma(X)) \mathbf{1}_{\{X \in A\}})$. You can divide this by $P(X \in A)$ and obtain $P(Y \in B \mid X \in A) = \frac{1}{P(X \in A)} E(P(Y \in B \mid \sigma(X)) \mathbf{1}_{\{X \in A\}}),$ so "yes, we can know" but we need to know $P(X \in A)$ in advance.

We know $P(X \in A)$ already. Do you mean that we need to know $\mathbf{1}_{{X \in A}}$ in advance?
